# Last path of URL

Tags: javascript

Small problem. Currently I have such code :
`const { pathname } = window.location; const paths = pathname.split("/").filter(entry => entry !== ""); const lastPath = paths[paths.length - 1];`

My URL looks like this: https://example.com/sbm_feedback/?agent=Ben&score=4&ticketid=12345

The output I get by this code is: **sbm_feedback**

What I want to get is: **?agent=Ben&score=4&ticketid=12345**

It probably just needs just a small change but I'm not a dev at all. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't quite understand the requirement's actual purpose. but `"?" + (pathname.split("?")[1])` will give you everything in the url after "?"

Comment: That’s not the pathname. That’s the search query. `location.search`. Read the documentation: [`location`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Location), [`URL`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/URL).